# Counting duplicate characters

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I can't figure out why the last character in a string always gets omitted when I try the following:

```
def duplicate_count(text):
    num = 0
    count = {}
    for char in text:
        print(count.items())
        if char in count.keys():
            count[char] += 1
        else:
            count [char] = 1
    for key in count:
        if count[key] == 1:
           num = 0
        else:
           num = count[key] - 1
    return (num)

char_s = 'abcde'
print (duplicate_count(char_s))
```

Comment: Add the following information to your question: 1) What do you think your function does. 2) What output do you get. 3) What output were you expecting and why. Do not post this as a comment. Hit the edit button under your question and put it directly in there.

Comment: It isn't omitted.  Your function prints `count.items()` _before_ adding the new character, so the char appears to be missing, but it really isn't.

Comment: It's allso worth putting some actual duplicates in your `char_s` variable for testing...

Answer (score 2):

You only output the counts before a given character is added, so you will never see the final counts. You could move your print statement to after your `if` if you'd like to change that.

The other issue is that your program is only returning the duplicate count of the last entry in your dictionary. You would need to create a new dictionary, or take the highest value of num, depending on your requirements

Answer (score 2):

The last character doesn't get omitted, it has not yet been added to `count` when you call `print(count.items())`.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion this could use some more segmentation. In my opinion you should not be focused on counting duplicate letters; you should narrow the scope of your function to identifying which letters occur, and how many times they occur. This can be easily stored in a dictionary variable.

Example:

```
def string_occurence (string):
    dict={}
    for char in string:
        dict [char]=string.count (char)
    return dict
```

You can also optimise this by creating a set of unique characters before checking the string:

```
def string_occurence (string):
    char_set=set ([char for char in string])
    dict={}
    for char in char_set:
        dict [char]=string.count (char)
    return dict
```

This hinges on how you want your control flow to work, but I think the second function would work best for you.